# Get Logged On User IBM Personal Communications in VBScript Macro

Tags: macros, vbscript, client, ibm-midrange

We Use IBM Personal Communications iSeries Access for Windows version 6.0. When you launch the program you initially get a Log on Prompt that lets you enter a server, user name and password.

It then gives you the log on screen to the server itself and you have to log on a second time. Between the two log ons I'm trying to work out a "Startup Macro"

I don't have anything in it right now because I cannot figure out how to get ONE particular value from the Session, the USER NAME.

I can get the screen title, session name, macro name, but I can NOT for the life of me figure out how to get the user name. I've tried every possible combination of strings and "variable" names I can think of, and nothing.

I've searched the web and all I can ever find is how to record and auto logon to the green screen which is not what I want.

To be clear I just need the Username used to logon to the Personal Communications iSeries Access for Windows program, pre green-screen logon.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to note that IBM i Access for Windows is much more than just the 5250 emulator.  There's an ODBC driver, a printer emulator, AFP printer drivers and the graphical Navigator for i.  That IBM i signon popup doesn't come from the 5250 emulator.  It comes from a lower level IBM i Access for Windows process.  Try it yourself.  Reboot the PC.  Don't start the emulator.  DO start IBM i Navigator for Windows.  You'll get the signon popup.

It looks like you are trying to automate a 'no signon' signon.  The user name is probably stored in the registry, depending on the version of Windows you are using and the version of IBM i Access for Windows.  Windows 7: Start > All Programs > IBM i Access for Windows > IBM I Access for Windows Properties  Choose the Administration System tab and you'll see the server and user.  HKCU > Software > IBM > Client Access Express > CurrentVersion > AS400 Operations Navigator > Application Administration > CurrentAdminSysUser > My Connections

Comment: For me, it's under ...> CurrentVersion > Environments > My Connections > hostName > Communication > User ID, where "hostName" is the connection host name. The location can be dependent on how the connection is configured.

Comment: It's more of I need to ensure that the user account used to sign into personal communication is the same account that is connected to the IFS via a windows drive mapping and prompt for a remap if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think, for this, you need to get into the ActiveX Control that comes with iSeries Access.  This little code C# snippet should work:

```
AS400System sys1 = new AS400System();
sys1.Define("mySystemNameHere");
if (sys1.IsConnected(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceAny) != 1)
{
    sys1.Connect(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceTelnet);
}
String user = sys1.UserID;
sys1.Disconnect(cwbcoServiceEnum.cwbcoServiceAll);
```

You'll need to find cwbx.dll and add it as a reference to your project.

If the user is already connected from another application, no dialog will appear.  The program will connect, get the connected user id, and then disconnect.  If the user has never connected since logging in, then a logon dialog will appear.

Comment: This looks promising going to fire up the ISE and see what kind of powershell/.NET magic I can conjure tomorrow morning.

Comment: I was able to get this working but is there a way to have .NET check the status of another connection started by another program e.g. Emulator?

Comment: You'll have to have your .Net program also make a connection.  If the user has already connected, then the password prompt won't happen.  It'll just connect, have a user id, and then disconnect.